# Golub leukemia dataset: Affy IDs to HUGO Symbols (or other)

Tags: r, generics, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have troubles to convert Affy ids to some other standard symbols for further processing:
The data I'm working with is the leukemia data set (Golub et al., 1999).
I use the golubEsets data set retrieved from Bioconductor project.

I tried this tutorial (http://faculty.washington.edu/kenrice/sisg/sisg-sea09-09.pdf)
with

```
# library for annotation
library("annotate")
library("hgu95av2.db")
library("GO.db")
#library for golub data set
library(golubEsets)
data(Golub_Merge)
geneids <- featureNames(Golub_Merge)
# retrieve something usefull (e.g. gene name)
mget(geneids, hgu95av2GENENAME)
```

This would produce many errors, because most of the Affy ids in the Golub data set weren't found in the database. Praticularly for this data set, where can I find some standard symbols (HUGO?) - because I need them to conduct further analysis.

Thank you!

Comment: This should rather be asked on biostar (http://www.biostars.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Golub dataset isn't produced from a hgu95av2 affymetrix chip. It used the older hu6800.

Just typing Golub_Merge at the R command line will give you the summary information and list the Annotation field as "Annotation: hu6800"

See http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.6/data/annotation/html/hu6800.db.html for the correct annotation library.